# Why user.home returns "\" not "/"?

Tags: java, windows

Maybe some of you will tell me where the mistake is, because I'm sitting on this for a few hours and didnt see anything.

The program should check if the `if` can be found in a txt file and return it to the bottom.

The second question about user.home
When I use it gets `"C: \ Users \ Daniel / test / Test.java"` by which the program does not work when I set the path to `"C :/ Users / Daniel / test / Test.java"` program begins to find my `.txt` file, but i cant leave it like that it must be found by `user.home` :(

```
public class Main {

      public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception  {
      String usrHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
      Finder finder = new Finder(usrHome + "/Testy/Test.java");
      int nif = finder.getIfCount();
      System.out.println("Number found 'if'": " + nif);
      }
}
```

And finder class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Finder {
String file;
Finder(String file){
        file = this.file;
}

int getIfCount() throws FileNotFoundException{  
    int count = 0;  String tmp; String lf = "if";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("C:/Users/Daniel/Testy/Test.java"));
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            tmp = sc.next();
            System.out.println(tmp); //to check if it works correctly
            if(tmp == lf){
                count++;
            }
        }

        sc.close();

    return count;
}


}
```

The result should look like this:

Number found "if": 3

Because there are three such elements, although the result is always 0

Comment: since the path-separater are system dependent, it will return \ in windows and / in linux. moreover, you should use single convention, either keep \ or / at everyplace in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the result is always 0

Because you use `==` with `String`, try to Use `equals()` when you compare two `string`

```
 if (tmp.equals(lf)) {
          count++;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do the filename concatenation would be this:

```
File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
File file = new File(home, "Testy/Test.java");
/* Or even ...
File file = new File(new File(home, "Testy"), "Test.java");
*/
Finder finder = new Finder(file);
```

This avoids needing to know about the platform pathname representation.

The miscounting issue is caused by a basic Java 101 mistake.  You are using '==' to compare Strings.  It (usually) doesn't work.  Use `String.equals(...)`.

Comment: Yes i know, but i cant change anything in main class :(

Comment: So do you have any evidence that your program is failing to open the file?  Is it throwing an exception?  Getting the count wrong is not evidence.  That is caused by a different bug.

Comment: ahhh sorry nvm, becouse it was my fault :). I wrote
 
    file = this.file 

when i should write 

    this.file = file

becouse in this way it was looking for file in empty path